# Same data displaying in Listview using custom adapterview from the sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, for-loop, android-custom-view

i am having error in getting user details in sqlite.

i want to display the these three user details by searching the data base but it showing the same user details three times not three different user details.

Here is my code

```
Cursor c= mydatabase.query(true, TABLENAME_1, new String[] { KEY_Name,
            KEY_CellPhoneNumber,KEY_CompanyName,KEY_Email_id }, KEY_Name + " LIKE ?",
            new String[] {"%"+ name+ "%" }, null, null, null,
            null);
```

i am retriving the details in the `AsynchTask` and in `doingBackGround` is in which i am having problem with loop please any body solve it..

```
DataHelper databasehelper = new DataHelper(Search.this);
            databasehelper.open();
            Cursor c= databasehelper.getAllCustomerDetailsByName(_name);    
if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0) {

                    int nam = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Name);
                    int cellnumber = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CellPhoneNumber);
                    int company = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CompanyName);
                    int emailid = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Email_id);
                    flag_data = true;
                    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
                    {

                    searchmodel.setName(c.getString(nam));
                    searchmodel.setCellphone(c.getString(cellnumber));
                    searchmodel.setCompany(c.getString(company));
                    searchmodel.setEmailid(c.getString(emailid));
                    Log.i("Search", searchmodel.getName());
                    Log.i("Search", searchmodel.getCellphone());
                    Log.i("Search", searchmodel.getCompany());
                    Log.i("Search", searchmodel.getEmailid());

                    for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount();i++)  {
                        customerSearch.add(i,searchmodel);

                        Log.i("index", ""+i);




                }

                    }



                }
```

my customer adapter class is

```
public class CustomerSearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<CustomerSearchModel> customerSearchData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context _context;

    public CustomerSearchAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<CustomerSearchModel> listData) {
        this.customerSearchData = listData;

        _context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return customerSearchData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return customerSearchData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (layoutInflater == null)
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_user_details,
                    null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.customer_user_name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            holder.customer_company_name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.company_name);
            holder.customer_phone_number = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
            holder.customer_emailid_number = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.emailid_number);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final CustomerSearchModel customDetailItem = (CustomerSearchModel) customerSearchData
                .get(position);

        holder.customer_user_name.setText(customDetailItem.getName());
        holder.customer_company_name.setText(customDetailItem.getCompany());
        holder.customer_phone_number.setText(customDetailItem.getCellphone());
        holder.customer_emailid_number.setText(customDetailItem.getEmailid());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView customer_user_name;
        TextView customer_company_name;
        TextView customer_phone_number;
        TextView customer_emailid_number;
    }

}
```

Comment: it is not an error it is a display problem of the user details form the sqlite,i want to display the three user details which are of three different people of there name starting from the same letters it is displaying the same name repeatedly can any please solve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display the user details from the data base by the search by using like in the sqlite query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212393/display-the-user-details-from-the-data-base-by-the-search-by-using-like-in-the-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `searchmodel` `variable` globally. you need to create new object of `Searchmodel` each time in `for loop`.

Remove `searchmodel` `global variable`.

I assume name of class is `Searchmodel` then you can try this:

```
DataHelper databasehelper = new DataHelper(Search.this);
databasehelper.open();
Cursor c= databasehelper.getAllCustomerDetailsByName(_name);    
if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0) {

      int nam = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Name);
      int cellnumber = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CellPhoneNumber);
      int company = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CompanyName);
      int emailid = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Email_id);
      flag_data = true;
      for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
           Searchmodel searchmodel = new Searchmodel();
           searchmodel.setName(c.getString(nam));
           searchmodel.setCellphone(c.getString(cellnumber));
           searchmodel.setCompany(c.getString(company));
           searchmodel.setEmailid(c.getString(emailid));
           Log.i("Search", searchmodel.getName());
           Log.i("Search", searchmodel.getCellphone());
           Log.i("Search", searchmodel.getCompany());
           Log.i("Search", searchmodel.getEmailid());

           for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount();i++)  {
                  customerSearch.add(i,searchmodel);
                  Log.i("index", ""+i);
           }

      }
}
```

Comment: thank you rajesh Jadav it works for me thaks for your answer